# How to use RawSocket In Dart?

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io, dart, flutter

I have server socket and when I access it with java setting the socket.setSoLinger(true,0); is works very well. I am trying to implement java client code with dart and I keep getting an error. Also it takes time to get the error. Dart suppose to be fast!

In java I open the socket as **socketOut = new DataOutPutStream(socket.getOutputStream()); and socketIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());**

and than I can use **socketOut.write(queryStr.getBytes());** to write and I can use **response += socketIn.readLine();** to read.

For my demo Dart Project I wrote below code and I keep getting the beloww error.

**Error:**

```
Unhandled exception:
SocketException: OS Error: Broken pipe, errno = 32, address = ***.***.***.***, port = 48620
#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1112:29)
#1      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#2      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#3      _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

**Dart Code:**

```
import 'package:untitled/untitled.dart' as untitled;
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

Socket socket;
String _dataToBeSent = "00802020N0307809491508590203000000000000490012001629   01700CD0";
var reply;

// TODO: MAIN
main(List<String> arguments) {

  _remoteServerConnect();

}

// TODO: REMOTE SERVER  CONNECT
void _remoteServerConnect() async {
  try {
      var socket = await Socket.connect('***.***.***.***', *****);
      socket.writeln('$_dataToBeSent\n');

      await for (var data in socket) {
        reply = new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim();
        print("reply: $reply");

        socket.close();
        socket.destroy();
      } // await socket

      socket.handleError((data) {
        print("error: $data");
      });

  } on Error catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  } on Exception catch (f) {
    print(f.toString());
  }
}
```

I am not sure. But something tells me that I should have to use RawSocket. And my quesiton is How to use RawSocket In Dart?

**UPDATE-1:** After reading a link I manage to recode my socket as shown below. But this time I am getting socket.write error.

```
// TODO: REMOTE SERVER  CONNECT
void _remoteServerConnect()  {
  Socket.connect('***.***.***.***', *****).then((Socket sock) {
    socket = sock;
    socket.listen(dataHandler,
        onError: errorHandler,
        onDone: doneHandler,
        cancelOnError: false);
  }).catchError((AsyncError e) {
    print("Unable to connect: $e");
    exit(1);
  });

  print(_dataToBeSent);
  socket.write(_dataToBeSent);
}

void dataHandler(data){
  print(new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim());
}

void errorHandler(error, StackTrace trace){
  print(error);
}

void doneHandler(){
  socket.destroy();
  exit(0);
}
```

I got an error in "socket.write(_dataToBeSent);" line saying that The method 'write' was called on null.

```
00802020N0307809491508590203000000000000490012001629   01700CD0
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'write' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: write(""00802020N0307809491508590203000000000000490012001629   01700CD0"")
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:48:5)
#1      _remoteServerConnect (file:///home/capital/IdeaProjects/untitled/bin/main.dart:31:10)
#2      main (file:///home/capital/IdeaProjects/untitled/bin/main.dart:13:3)
#3      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:287:32)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
```

**UPDATE-2:** If I use Future than I cannot see any data but it runs without error.

// TODO: REMOTE SERVER  CONNECT

```
Future _remoteServerConnect() async {
  await Socket.connect('***.***.***.***', ******).then((Socket sock) {
    socket = sock;
    socket.listen(dataHandler,
        onError: errorHandler,
        onDone: doneHandler,
        cancelOnError: false);
  }).catchError((AsyncError e) {
    print("Unable to connect: $e");
    exit(1);
  });

  print(_dataToBeSent);
  await socket.write(_dataToBeSent);
}

void dataHandler(data){
  print(new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim());
}

void errorHandler(error, StackTrace trace){
  print(error);
}

void doneHandler(){
  socket.destroy();
  exit(0);
}
```

**The Result:**

```
00802020N02018092108262302030000000000005494490012001629   00000000
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I don't think `socket.close();` and `socket.destroy();` should be inside `await for ... { ... }`. This would close the socket every time after a chunk of data arrived. Also the `socket.handleError(...)` part should be moved before `await for` otherwise it will only be added after the socket was closed.

Comment: If you use `socket.writeln` you shouldn't need to add `\n` to the data.

Comment: this link might be useful: http://jamesslocum.com/post/67566023889

Comment: @Feu good find. It doesn't use `async` `await` but starting with code known to work is usually a good idea.

Comment: Ok,I will look at the suggestion. In my java client code I also use socket.setSoLinger(true,0) and it worked. In java client if I comment this line is not working. What is the equivalent setSoLinger in Dart or what should I make to come close for this?

Comment: I update my question and re-write my client socket part. But now I am getting error on socket.write line, and idea?

Comment: I update again and use Future this time, the socket runs without error but I cannot get any value back.

Comment: Ok, I mange to get data back with error. Error is: SocketException: OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno=104, address = remote_address, port = 40558, any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: I get data first time and if I try to get data second time (with 1 or 2 seconds delay) I get above error as well as I get anonymous closure error

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is still relevant, but there is a potential error in the code. Instead of trying to set `socket = sock` inside the callback for `connect`, you should set it to the awaited value that is returned by the connect method.

```
Future _remoteServerConnect() async {
  socket = await Socket.connect('***.***.***.***', ******).then((Socket sock) {
    sock.listen(dataHandler,
        onError: errorHandler,
        onDone: doneHandler,
        cancelOnError: false);
  }).catchError((AsyncError e) {
    print("Unable to connect: $e");
    exit(1);
  });

  print(_dataToBeSent);
  await socket.write(_dataToBeSent);
}

void dataHandler(data){
  print(new String.fromCharCodes(data).trim());
}

void errorHandler(error, StackTrace trace){
  print(error);
}

void doneHandler(){
  socket.destroy();
  exit(0);
}
```